# I'm trying to permanently change fits headers using astropy hdu.writeto has added "None" to my fits file

Tags: astropy, fits

I want to

1. read in a fits file
2. change some of the headers
3. save it, with the changes, to a new fits file.

So far I think I have achieved this, however the new fits file has "None" when I do hdu.info(). I'm confused what this means, why it's there, and is it bad?

I'll paste my code below with the associated outputs:

```
from astropy.io import fits
hdulist = fits.open('2D_comb_ff_wavcal_red_sci_2.fits')
hdu = hdulist[0]
hdulist.info()
```

> ```
> Filename: 2D_comb_ff_wavcal_red_sci_2.fits 
> No.    Name      Ver    Type      Cards   Dimensions   Format 
>  0  PRIMARY       1 PrimaryHDU     287   (1024, 1024)   float32
> ```

```
print 'CRVAL1 then = ', hdu.header['CRVAL1']
print 'CRVAL2 then = ', hdu.header['CRVAL2']
```

> ```
> CRVAL1 then =  14975.1660156 
> CRVAL2 then =  1.0
> ```

```
CRVAL1_orig = hdu.header['CRVAL1']
CRVAL2_orig = hdu.header['CRVAL2']

hdu.header['CRVAL1'] = CRVAL2_orig
hdu.header['CRVAL2'] = CRVAL1_orig

print 'CRVAL1 now = ',  hdu.header['CRVAL1']
print 'CRVAL2 now = ',  hdu.header['CRVAL2']
```

> ```
> CRVAL1 now =  1.0 
> CRVAL2 now =  14975.1660156
> ```

```
hdu.writeto('newheader.fits', overwrite=True)
new = fits.open('newheader.fits')
print new.info()
```

> ```
> Filename: newheader.fits 
> No.    Name      Ver    Type      Cards   Dimensions   Format 
>   0  PRIMARY       1 PrimaryHDU     287   (1024, 1024)   float32   
> None
> ```

The headers have updated (I checked) but why does it say "None" here? Is hdu.writeto() the wrong thing? I've tried reading about flush() but it confused me.

Thanks

Comment: The answer below is correct. I'll just add that you almost never need to worry about file I/O methods like `flush()` or even `close()`. If you don't understand what they're for then you're probably not using the library at a level where you'd need them in the first place. You might find it more edifying also to actually print the header itself, since `.info()` by itself is not all that informative

Answer (score 2):

That is because you are printing what is returned from `.info()`. Note in the fourth line you have

```
hdulist.info()
```

with no `print`, yet you get the output you expect. furthermore you do get properly

```
0 PRIMARY 1 PrimaryHDU 287 (1024, 1024) float32
```

when you call `new.info()`. So to sum, it is the method itself which prints, likely not returning anything or returning `None` by default, and since you `print` it, it gets displayed as a string.

Just remove the final `print`.

Comment: I'll add that assuming you're using the IPython console or notebook you can run `hdulist.info??` to see the source code for the method, and that it already calls `print()` and does not explicitly return a value (all Python functions have a default return value of `None` if no explicit `return` statement is given)